# File's properties: lastModified vs lastModifiedDate

Tags: javascript

[On the following page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) they mention `lastModified` and `lastModifiedDate`. `lastModifiedDate` is working in every browser for me (FF, Chrome, IE, Edge, Opera) but it is written that is deprecated. `lastModified` doesn't exist in IE or Edge. So which to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the correct procedure is to verify programmatically if lastModified is available and in that case use it; if it is not available you should fallback to the deprecated one. In this case you are guaranteed to use the most "uptodated" standard if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use whichever is available, preferably the non-deprecated one:

```
var lastModified = file.lastModified || file.lastModifiedDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `lastModifiedDate` is `deprecated`  and works in every browser but `lastModified` isn't working in `IE` and `Edge`, you can write a test to see if `lastModified` is available so you can use it, otherwise use the deprecated one.

```
if(File.lastModified){
  //Do whatever you want using File.lastModified
}else{
  //Use File.lastModifiedDate 
}
```

Just make sure you test for `lastModified` in the first place as it isn't deprecated, so you avoid using the `deprecated` one in most cases.