# Using File in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing a web application using Angular 4 and Typescript. I need the date of a file to upload and try to use the File objects lastModified property, but Typescript gives me an error

```
Property 'lastModified' does not exist on type 'File'.
```

If I look in the definition it instead have the lastModifiedDate as a property. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModifiedDate that property is depriciated. I have however tried it and it works in Chrome, but fails in Safari.

How can I use File lastModified property from Typescript?

Comment: Please provide peace of code for people to see if you are doing it right.

Comment: But File.lastModified does not exist in lib.dom.d.ts: interface: 
 File extends Blob {
    readonly lastModifiedDate: any;
    readonly name: string;
    readonly webkitRelativePath: string;
}

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16942

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
interface MyFile extends File {
    lastModified: any;
}

let myFile = <MyFile>originalFile;
let lm = myFile.lastModified;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also for [lastModifiedDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModifiedDate), which is deprecated but for now still around in [Chrome](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_file_lastmodifieddate) and was the [only option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44115976/files-properties-lastmodified-vs-lastmodifieddate) in IE:

```ts
// use non-deprecated lastModified field instead 
new Date(file.lastModified)


// in-line type assertion
(file as unknown as { lastModifiedDate: Date }).lastModifiedDate

// type assertion with special type
type DateFile = File & {
  lastModifiedDate: Date;
};
...
(file as DateFile).lastModifiedDate
```

will prevent TS2551 `Property 'lastModifiedDate' does not exist on type 'File'. Did you mean 'lastModified'? ts(2551)` error by using [lastModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified) instead or [asserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204759/typescript-or-javascript-type-casting/35362350#35362350) that it exists.